# Interpreting this Riemann Intergral problem

Tags: real-analysis

I saw this on the message board and am very interested in this problem.

The question reads as the following.

Let $f$ be continuous on interval $[0,1]$. Prove that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(\frac{k}{n})= \int_0^1f(x)dx$$

The person then stated this

Again any help would be greatly appreciate. I have attempted throwing the definition of continuity at it cause it states that it is continuous. I then used a uniform partition  and stated my $M_k$, $m_k$ based on the equation. I had my partition looking like this $P=({0}\frac{1}{n},\frac{2}{n},...,\frac{n}{n})$.

Now I'm having a hard time interpreting the sum on the left. Is this a collection of rational numbers on the interval $[0,1]$? I know that the rationals are dense so there are an infinite amount of points in this interval? Am I reading this correctly?

Comment: Is this the correct way to be interpreting the equation? Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: The LHS can be interpreted as the limit of right Riemann sums of $f$ over $[0,1]$ with uniform partition of mesh $\frac{1}{n}$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: You just posted this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757274/riemann-intergral-proof-question#comment1575067_757274 a few hours ago.